# Retrieve memory of Bitmap/Drawable

Tags: android, bitmap

I need the raw bitmap memory of an Android drawable (the app icon). By raw bitmap I mean the memory representation of the image. (I need it for reading in a c++ Qt app, to convert that image to Qt formats).

So far I can't find a way to get the memory either of a Drawable Bitmap or Canvas. One way would be geting each pixel's colors but I foresee this uneficient/slow.

Is that possible? Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the raw bytes? If so you can read it into a byte array. This is pseudo code but something like this.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

bitmap.compress(stream);

byte[] byte = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Yes something like that but this one would not give the raw bytes but a compressed representation (can't find a "null" CompressFormat). At least I could "decode" the result from a PNG, will wait if there's some more straight suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
bitmap.writeToParcel(parcel p, int flags); 
parcel.readByteArray(byte[] array);
```

hope that gets you there. ha

Comment: Nope, what i need is the raw bytes of the bitmap, that would work to store the bitmap and later retrieving it but I need the raw data.